# Debugging Golang in VS Code using delve doesn't work properly

Tags: visual-studio, go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am in the process of setting up Visual Studio Code for Golang, however debugging is not working properly. I get the following output:

```
Starting: /home/shaze/go/bin/dlv-dap dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:37317 --log-dest=3 from /home/shaze/go/new
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:37317
Type 'dlv help' for list of commands.
user1
20
Process 74396 has exited with status 0
Detaching
dlv dap (74287) exited with code: 0
```

The launch script looks like this:

```
 {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Launch Package",
                "type": "go",
                "request": "launch",
                "mode": "debug",
                "program": "${fileDirname}"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Go env:

```
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/shaze/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/shaze/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/shaze/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/shaze/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.6"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build262010564=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

**Unfortunately, the debugger shows nothing:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUvbt.png

I believe that something isn't connected here correctly. I appreciate any help, thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Your debugger is working fine and finished the execution properly. If you want to see the program state at a time you need to add a break point.